# Acumatica table for inventory item last cost

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to find table to extract last cost of an item as defined under Stock Items--Price/cost Info--Last Cost. Data class name is displayed as INItemCost, however I cannot find it in database?
Any ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be the **INItemStats** table in database:

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<InventoryItem, 
    LeftJoin<INItemStatsTotal, 
        On<INItemStatsTotal.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>, 
    LeftJoin<INSite, 
        On<INSite.siteID, Equal<InventoryItem.dfltSiteID>>>>, 
    Where<INItemStatsTotal.nextCostDate, IsNull>>))]
[PXCacheName(Messages.ItemCostStatistics)]
[Serializable]
public partial class INItemCost : IBqlTable
{
    ...
    #region LastCost
    public abstract class lastCost : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBPriceCost(BqlField = typeof(INItemStatsTotal.lastCost))]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Cost", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual Decimal? LastCost { get; set; }
    #endregion
    ...
}

[PXBreakInheritance]
[Serializable]
[PXHidden]
public partial class INItemStatsTotal : INItemStats
{
    ...
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXCacheName(Messages.INItemStats)]
public partial class INItemStats : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
    ...
    #region LastCost
    public abstract class lastCost : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBPriceCost()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Cost", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual Decimal? LastCost { get; set; }
    #endregion
    ...
}
```